# How can I give Diamond Armour to Villagers in MCA?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-comes-alive

I'm using the Minecraft Comes Alive mod for Minecraft 1.7.10 and I want to equip the villagers in my world with diamond armour.

I cannot put it in their inventory or gift the armour to them, so how do I get them to equip it?

Comment: Hi Brendan! I don't believe we support modded Minecraft here.

Comment: @TheUnicornMaster we still support questions about mods, but we don't do tech support (crash help) for nodded minecraft.

Comment: @TrentHawkins woops! I wasn't sure. sorry Brendan, please feel free to ask these sort of mod-related questions

Comment: Questions asking about mod contents are welcome here,so long it's not asking about mod support. @TheUnicornMaster

Comment: Yeah,it's a hard thing to equip in MCA. For example,if your wife is a guard,her sword will dissapear,but she will still patrol,and I don't know how to give her a sword.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set up dispensers so that the villagers will be forced to wear the armor.

1. Place dispensers in a row (facing the same direction).
2. Put your desired armour in them.
3. Pace one line of redstone in front of the dispenser's "mouth" an place a pressure plate in front of that.
4. Have the villagers walk on the pressure plates to activate the dispensers which should shoot the armour into the villagers and equip them with the armour.

If everything goes right, you should have armoured, warrior traders!

Answer (score 0):

In normal Minecraft you can't give armor to villagers and the only solution is to use dispenser to hit them with armor. That is very easy to remember because it works on normal player too.

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone in 1.12.2 see this, backup your file, and turn the main into a zip, after this unpack it and go into "MCA-1.12.2-6.1.0-universal\assets\mca\api\gui\Main.json" and open it as a text in notepad, after this find the gui.button.inventory, change the y to 105 and remove the everything in the constraints quote, repack the mod(make sure the repack is exactly as the main was) put it into your mods folder and launch, you now have access to all villager inventories and can equip them with any armor you want manually.